# Rails route helper for has_one associative object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, model-associations

I have a `User` model and a `Shoppingcart` model where

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :shoppingcart
end
```

and

```
# shopppingcart.rb
class Shoppingcart < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

and I have this in routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
    resource :shoppingcart
end
```

I would like to get the route helper that will take the to the `Shoppingcart` for the designated `User`. I've tried looking this up but I haven't seen an example of this with a `has_one` relationship, only with `has_many`. Does anyone know how to get these route helpers?

Comment: use `ShoppingCart`  instead `Shoppingcart`

Comment: For cosmetics? Because I named the class `Shoppingcart`

Answer (score 1):

Your routes will be like this for `shoppingcart#show` action for given user.

```
user_shoppingcart_path GET /users/:user_id/shoppingcart/:id(.:format)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

`user_shoppingcart_path(@user)`

you can use the new and edit actions by adding their respective prefix. Using the patch/put and delete actions are HTTP Verb dependent. Since this is a singular resource, there is no index action.